# DatePicker Javascript pass array of allowed times on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

im still finding my way around with both jquery and JS. im using the plugin for date time picker here http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and i need to pass an array of allowed times in.

Basically the documentation states this

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes:[
  '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
  '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
 ]
});
```

What i was wondering was is there a way to pass in an array here? Ive tried creating a function and doing allowed:getArr() but it didnt work

```
function getArr() {
            var allowTimes = [
  '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', 
  '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '19:00', '20:00'
 ];
        return allowTimes;

    }
```

is this how it should be done or is it a limitation of the plugin is what im trying to figure out?

Comment: You want to get allowedTimes from #picker5 right?

Comment: Please provide your entire invocation of `datetimepicker` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely you are passing `allowTimes` a reference to the function instead of invoking it to return the results.

If you're code looks like the following:

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes: function getArr() {
        var allowTimes = [
           '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', 
           '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '19:00', '20:00'
        ];
    return allowTimes;
 }
});
```

You will want to change it to the following:

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
 datepicker:false,
 allowTimes: function getArr() {
        var allowTimes = [
           '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', 
           '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '19:00', '20:00'
        ];
    return allowTimes;
 }()
});
```

Comment: not exactly what i implemented but got me on the right track so for that you get the kudos - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late here but I had the same problem and solved it like this:
I created a `comma separated string` from a `JSON` response.
Then when initializing the `datetimepicker` I passed the `allowTimes` `option` as follows:

```
$('.delivery').datetimepicker({
                datepicker:false,
                timepicker:true,
                format:'H:i',
                step:30,
                allowTimes: function getArr() {
                    var allowTimes = str_times.split(',');
                    return allowTimes;
                }()

            });
        })
```

Where `str_times` is a `string` like this:

```
str_times = "12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00"
```

Of course you can create this `string` from any type of `data`.